# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3 n+6 i}{(1+2 i)^n}$ converges.

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3 n+6 i}{(1+2 i)^n}$ converges. So I am applying the root test:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} |\sqrt[n]{\frac{3 n+6 i}{(1+2 i)^n}}|$$
and I have some difficulties with this limit.

I got up to here:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\dfrac{\log \left(3 (1+2 i)^{-n} (n+2 i)\right)}{n}}$$

How should I go on with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{n+2i}{(1+2i)^n}\right|\leq\frac{\sqrt{n^2+4}}{\sqrt{5}^n}\leq\frac{n+2}{2^n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\lvert 1+2i\rvert = \sqrt{5} > 1$, and any series with terms of the form $\frac{n^k}{\rho^n}$ with $k\geq 0$ and $\rho > 1$ converges.